Can we find a normal nilpotent subgroup $G$ of monomial subgroup of $GL_n(D)$ such that $F[G]=M_n(D)$?
Let $D$ be a non-commutative division ring of finite dimension over its center $F$. Also, $n>1$ is a natural number. Consider that $M$ be the monomial subgroup of $GL_n(D)$(containing $n \times n$ matrices
with entries in $D$ such that exactly one entry of each row and each column is
nonzero). Can we find a normal nilpotent subgroup $G$ of $M$ such that $F[G]=M_n(D)?$ When $F[G]$ is the ring generated by $G$ and $F$.
